# Epoch, batch size and model complexity

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I had a very short question regarding neural network models. Is it better/differnt, if for example I have a simple neural network model with like 1000 epochs and a large batch size and run it till I get a fairly good loss and val_loss value, or a more complicated model with like 10-20 epochs and a very small batch.

Thank you.

Comment: These kind of questions have no answer, you must test for each case with your data. The `val_loss` and other val metrics will answer it for you.

Comment: It's good to see class.coursera.org/ml-005/lecture/preview course, especially for you week 4-6 + 10. Wikipedia may be not so valuable resource for learning neural networks